# Managing archived databases in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server 2012 database server that has 3 databases.

The databases are as follows:

1. System X: Our production database, that is used daily.
2. System X: The initial database we received from the vendor after our data migration.
3. The source data we submitted to the vendor for conversion.

The latter two databases are only used for querying and I am the only user that accesses them, which only happens on rare occasions when there are questions about the provenance of some piece of data ("That's been that way since before the migration").

What would be the best practice for managing the two archival databases?

- Taking them offline; and then bringing them online when they are needed.
- Detaching them and then reattaching them when they are needed.
- Saving a backup of them, then deleting them from the server, and restoring them from the backup when they are needed.

I'm not sure which would be best practice or the relative advantages and/or disadvantages of each.

Comment: What are you worried about with having them online?

Comment: Yeah something seems a little oddball here. You would have to always need to have the disc space available if you are going to allow them to be attached at any time. What advantage are you hoping for by not having the databases available? Having a database attached is not a performance issue at all. But attaching a database will have a performance affect on the entire instance.

Comment: This seems to be the classic case of "I want to do everything right" without knowing the implications of what you are doing

Comment: There are many resources online about the negative impact of keeping databases in MySQL (eg: https://haydenjames.io/mysql-performance-drop-unused-databases/), but I couldn't find any similar resources for SQL Server. If there's nothing wrong with keeping them online, then I'm happy to keep them online.

Comment: Just keep them online. It takes more resources to attach a database than it does just letting it sit there. If the database is not in use it consumes no resources. Apparently mysql is a bit different in that regards. Wonder why they need to consume resources for a database that has no connections made to it.